# Stop and start an animation by touch. Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have made an animation that moves across the screen, my animation loops continuously. How can I stop the animation when you tap the animated image, Then let the animation continue when you lift the touch?

I know how to use TouchesMoved to move a specified button like this:

```
CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
UIControl *control = sender;
control.center = point;
```

But getting it to work with my animation. I would like the animation to continue after I touch it.

SelectedCellViewController.h

```
//  SelectedCellViewController.h

#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface SelectedCellViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
UIImageView *rocket;
}

@end
```

viewControllertoShow.m

```
#import "SelectedCellViewController.h"

@interface SelectedCellViewController ()

@end

@implementation SelectedCellViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[self performSelector:@selector(imageSpawn:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

}

- (void) imageSpawn:(id) sender
{

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ae"];
rocket = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
rocket.frame = CGRectMake(-25, 200, 25, 40);
[UIView animateWithDuration:5
                      delay:0.2f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^(){rocket.frame=CGRectMake(345, 200, 25, 40);}
                 completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                 }];

[self.view addSubview:rocket];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ballTapped:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
[rocket setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


}

-(void)ballTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

//then write code to remove the animation
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
rocket.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,location.y,25,40);
}

- (void)dismissView {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

@end
```

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know whether it helps

Comment: So I have updated my code I took out my myScrollView completely, now not even my log for the touch event works. My image animates correctly. but I get no touch event?

Comment: It just doesn't work, If I put an alert or log input into -(void)ballTapped it works , But I cannot make my animation stop?

Comment: @MicRO   I stopped my error now , but still can't seem to manage to stop my animation when I touch the screen.

Comment: see the **EDIT** section in my answer, update your code with it and check the result

Comment: @MicRO   So I did what you said and put the UIMageView *rocket into my header file , and changed my code accordingly , My animation works fine but nothing happens when I touch the screen? I have updated my code above accordingly. Thanks for this.

Comment: Thats all I could do without trying your project, check yourselves.I can't make more guesses good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you had already stated in your question ,you can get the touched point using

```
CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
```

Then  check check whether this point lies inside the coordinates of the animated `UIImageview` and then stop animation.
But if you are using scrollview, you won't be able to use this because scrollview will not return any `UIView` touch events.

As your image view is animating, a better choice will be adding a UITapGestureRecogniser to the image view when you add it s subview, like this

```
- (void) imageSpawn:(id) sender
{

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ae"];
UIImageView *rocket = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
rocket.frame = CGRectMake(-25, 200, 25, 40);
[UIView animateWithDuration:5
                      delay:0.2f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^(){rocket.frame=CGRectMake(345, 200, 25, 40);}
                 completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                 }];

[myScrollView addSubview:rocket];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ballTapped:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
    [rocket setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

And in the target function write code to stop the animation:

```
    -(void)ballTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
    //here also you can get the tapped point if you need
        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

    //then write code to remove the animation
        [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; 
     }
```

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to stop the image view at the touched point, you can add this to ballTapped event:

```
rocket.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,location.y,25,40);
```

But for this you have to declare `UIImageView *rocket` outside this particular method, i.e. declare to in your header file.

Comment: I tried this . The animation works but nothing happens when I touch the image animating across the screen. No errros, The app does not crash?

Comment: if I use [myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapped]; instead of [rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped]; it works on the whole view, my NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag); works but this does not work [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];?

Comment: well, am not sure whats going on in your code, can you share some code so that i can have a better look?

Comment: I'm getting an error with [self.rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped]; not found on object of type for my viewcontroller? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: hey, if you have already synthesized "rocket", just use `[rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped];` , did your error got solved now?

Comment: I was playing around and I changed [rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; to [rocket addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; and it worked. Thanks very much for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add this to the parent view of the animation -

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.animating = NO;
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

use an (atomic) property, then check the property in the animation to see if it should be stopped. We use this to stop a photo gallery which is running so that the user can manually move the photos. You could also check in here if the point is in a specific area if necessary. This method runs before any touch methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it helps you, in the middle of the animation if you touch on the imageview then animation removes from the view .

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint lastLocation = [touch locationInView: self.view];

    if([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        [youImageView.layer removeAllAnimations]; 
        youImageView.center=lastLocation;//assign your image view center when the animation removes from the view.
    }
}
```

and add   `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework.

Comment: @Blake Loizides :once check this one.